# Where did the downloaded/installed plugin go?

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, claws

I just downloaded a Plugin for the Claws E-mail program:

`sudo apt-get install claws-mail-vcalendar-plugin`

And according to the instructions, all you need to do is to open it

```
USAGE

   Before using a plugin you must instruct Claws Mail to load it on
   startup.

   For this you must go “Configuration” menu on main window toolbar, open
   “Plugins...”  dialog, click on the “Load plugin...”  button and select
   the plugin file, named vcalendar.so, and press the “Open” button.
```

...But I cannot find **vcalender.so** in my home directory.

Any hints where I should look for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you, because the instructions seem quite straightforward.

In Claws Mail just click on Configuration -> Plugins... -> Load... and it should direct you right to the plugin directory where you find the vcalender.so

( this should be something like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/claws-mail/plugins` )

Comment: Strange, I went out to buy something and when I came back the Plugin showed up in the "Open"-Dialog, probably in the path you suggested.